# /etc/cron.hourly/asl exited with return code 127

Tags: debian, cron

The hourly configured cronjob `asl` started to exit with return code 127 since one day (after run of `apt-get update; apt-get dist-upgrade`).

Now I'm receiving hourly reports like:

```
run-parts: /etc/cron.hourly/asl exited with return code 127
```

Where does it come from? Config file looks quite fine.

/EDIT: I saw the "duplicate thread". Unfortunately there is only that one small chapter about cron.hourly scheduled jobs. All the logs files etc. are not mentioning anything. Executing the cron step by step shows following error:

```
root@s01:/etc/cron.hourly# /var/asl/bin/aum -u
Checking versions ... 

Updating Web Application Firewall to 201608111803: updated        [PASS]
Restarting Apache ... 
Generating report ... 

Finished
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Errors were encountered:

L CODE SOURCE                        MESSAGE
- ---- ----------------------------- ------------------------------------------
2 9901 ASLCommon::cmd_system         ERROR: '/bin/cp -af /var/asl/rules/modsec/
                                     template-* /var/asl/data/templates/ >/dev/
                                     null 2>&1 (1)'
```

Comment: I am reopening it as this is not a `cron` problem but a problem with the job as such. You should make this more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to an an update the config file was overwritten.
Quick fix Guide:

a) Exit code 1

ISSUE: error notifications with respect to cronjobs exiting with code 1.

SOLUTION 1: follow Plesk KB article KB129494, but I would not want to recommend it, for reasons that will become clear later.
SOLUTION 2: follow the steps below (in chronological order):

- run the command: `cp -p /etc/asl/config.dpkg-dist /etc/asl/config`
- run the command: `/var/asl/bin/aum -c`

and note that you should have the config.dpkg-dist file (on deb based machines, or the equivalent on rpm based machines), otherwise just use solution 1.

CHECK: verify that `/etc/asl/config` contains the key-value pair of `CONFIGURED="yes"` in the last line of the config file.

IMPORTANT: you are not finished yet, have a look at point b!

b) Exit code 127

ISSUE: error notifications with respect to cronjobs exiting with code 127.

SOLUTION: change the key-value pair `APACHE_RESTART_COMMAND="/etc/init.d/httpd restart"` to `APACHE_RESTART_COMMAND="/etc/init.d/apache2 restart"`, IF AND ONLY IF you are on a deb based machine (like Ubuntu).

CHECK: just have a look at /etc/init.d, in order to determine whether you should use "httpd" or "apache2".

IMPORTANT: in most cases of changes to or updates to mod_security and/or rulesets, Apache web server has to be restarted
IMPORTANT: do NOT use the "work-around" as mentioned in the post https://talk.plesk.com/threads/suddenly-getting-asl-errors-today.338907/page-2#post-806008
IMPORTANT: it is highly recommend to use the key-value pair RESTART_APACHE="graceful" (!)

NOTE: it is recommended to restart httpd or apache2 service after applying this solution.

Source: https://talk.plesk.com/threads/suddenly-getting-asl-errors-today.338907/page-2#post-806035

Answer (score 0):

Check the release notes of the version you upgraded to and check how the changes affect the software you are running in the cron job.